# Get all resources before starting on single-page-application JS

Tags: javascript, single-page-application

I have noumerous ajax calls on page Load and those calls bring neseesary resources to start application (JSON massives and functions).

The problem is, that those resources get loaded not strictly on after another, but asynchroniusly and before get in used they get formatted by success functions.

To start application a have to check that all resources loaded and have been formatted properly. The best way to do this I found is to run circle with timeOut, checking all of them unless all are ready. It doesn't seem right for me, couse it takes a while to start application, so I thought that may be there is another appoach.

I thought about getting setInterval function with a little timeout and a bunch of nested IF's, and at the end of those IF's I could cancel Interaval functin and start application.

May be soneone is familiar with right approach to such things and could share some code?

Comment: require.js is what you require.

Comment: require.js seems overdosed for me, I'm lookkng for simple circular dependent solution that can be run on a client